# Something weird happening with my Iceweasel tabs

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, appearance

What's going on with my Iceweasel tabs?

[image]

Comment: Try opening it in **safe mode** and see how it appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of problems like these are caused by extension, theme or hardware acceleration. To troubleshoot refer following steps.

1. Start Firefox in safe mode. If the problem does not occur in safe mode go further.
2. Turn hardware acceleration off. If problem is solved, update your graphics drivers.
3. Switch to default theme.
4. Disable extensions. If problem is solved test enabling extensions one by one.

Source: [Troubleshooting Firefox](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Troubleshooting%20extensions%20and%20themes)

Comment: I needed to install the nvidia non-free drivers